# How to parse simple toml in perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, toml

I need implement user friendly configuration file to my perl's script. I choose toml, but im not sure how working TOML parser.

backtest.toml file

```
strategies1 = [ neuralnet, BBRSI ];
```

script perl:

```
use TOML qw(from_toml to_toml);
use Data::Dumper;
my $toml = slurp("backtest.toml");
my $data = from_toml($toml);
print Dumper($data);
print Dumper($strategies1);
```

Comment: So what is your question? Does your code work?

Comment: I missed quotes in array. Now is working.

Comment: But I have another ask: howto parse toml variable to this same variable name in perl? Without hashes. In this case how to my $strategies = strategies(from toml)?

Comment: Then please write an *answer* that explains the resolution.

Comment: *Stack Overflow* is not a chat forum. You need to close this question by writing and accepting the answer that you've discovered, and then open a new question, this tine with proper detail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check error use the code

```
my ($data, $err) = from_toml($toml);
unless ($data) {
    die "Error parsing toml: $err";
}
```

Comment: Error parsing toml: Syntax Error: line:1
strategies1 =[ neuralnet, BBRSI ]

Comment: I missed quotes. Thanks!

Comment: wondering what is wrong with the accepted answer.  :) (downvoted)